# Need to move VM to another host with different cpu

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, migration

I currently have a VM configured with CPU 1 socket & 8 cores per socket. I need to move this VM to another ESXi 5.5 host which has 2 CPU sockets with 6 cores per socket.

Will I will able to run this VM configured with 8 cores (1 socket) in the new ESXi host ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can move the virtual machine from one host to the other.

It's less than ideal, since your VM will be scheduled across two physical CPUs, but it will definitely work.

Comment: will I need to make any changes to my VM as it is currently configured with 1 Socket and 8 cores for CPU? I am moving this VM from ESXi5.1 to ESXi5.5, completely different datastore.

Comment: No. You don't need to make any changes. But please reevaluate other you even *need* 8 cores for this VM. It's uncommon for me to give a virtual machine that many CPUs.